# RMySQL retrieving data from database table basing on an if statement

Tags: r, rmysql

I am trying to retrieve data from a database table based on a given condition:

I want to select all from a table, and during the while loop I put a condition like to return only what I want the way it is done in PHP

```
mytable <- dbSendQuery(con, "select date from member")

while(!dbHasCompleted(mytable)){
   if(name = 'myname'){

  new_date <- dbFetch(mytable, n=-1)
  print(mytable)

  }
}
```

How do I deal with the if statements to operate well?

Comment: I don't think you need the while loop. `dbFetch(mytable, n=-1)` will run until all the records have been collected.

Comment: But how do i deal with an if statement in case i want to retrieve data basing on a certain condition?

Comment: More information would be needed to answer this (and I'm not sure I quite understand what you are trying to do), but typically I'd do a query based on the name, and check that the resulting data has more than 0 row.

Comment: All i want is to retrieve data basing on a given condition from the database

for example if name = 'kay' and age = '15, 
the it retrieve it 

i dont want it to be in a query but rather a condition during the execution and retrieval of data in a while loo

Answer (score 0):

I later found out the solution like this

```
mytable <- dbSendQuery(con, "select * from member")

while(!dbHasCompleted(mytable)){

  new_date <- dbFetch(mytable, name = 'john', n=-1)
  print(new_date )

}
```